# Transferring save files for Stardew Valley to a new computer

Tags: steam, stardew-valley

I have a Steam account I have used for many years on a desktop gaming computer.  My wife started playing Stardew Valley on my account and she's hooked, so now I want to set her up with her own Steam account on a new gaming laptop, so that she and I can each play different games at the same time.  Is there any way to transfer her saved games to a new computer?  We can enable Family Sharing for her new account.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Stardew Valley wiki page](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Saves), save files are stored at `%appdata%\StardewValley\Saves`. So, here's a step by step tutorial.

1. Press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd>
2. Type in `%appdata%\StardewValley\Saves` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Find the save your wife uses, it'll look like `CharacterName_123456789`
4. Right click it
5. Go down to `Send to...`
6. Select `Compressed (zipped) folder`
7. Move the created `.zip` onto a portable USB
8. Unzip the folder on the new computer
9. Move the save back into `%appdata%\StardewValley\Saves`.

Comment: Note if you haven't done anything like this before, Windows might say you need administrator privileges and stuff - just say yes. This is only there because it is a weird place for the average user to go to.